# Compare strings ignore NUL

Tags: c++, string, stl

I'm trying to compare two `std::strings`, `"abc\0"` and `"abc"`.
Is there a way to ignore a character, in this case `'\0'` (NUL), when comparing?

Right now I'm doing a `pop_back()` on the string with the trailing NUL to remove it, but there must be a better way to handle this.

Comment: You *could* compare the C string with C string comparison functions (`strcmp` etc), this ignores `\0`. I'd still prefer the method you have now though.

Comment: How did the NUL get in there in the first place? That's what I would fix.

Comment: @SombreroChicken To be more precise: it doesn't ignore, it stops at first null character - so `"ab\0c"` and "abc" wouldn't compare equal either. If it's just at the end, though (`pop_back`!)...

Comment: @NeilButterworth: Irrelevant. NUL characters are perfectly valid within a `std::string`.

Comment: If you want to ignore specific characters in a string, if they aren't confined to the extremities of the string, it's not straight forward with standard algorithms. If the input strings are mutable, consider removing the null characters before comparing. You can always write your own algorithm.

Comment: @NicolBolas While NUL characters are perfectly valid within a `std::string`, based on the question, it doesn't seem like what's *intended*.

Comment: @Nicol Believe it or not, I do know that. The question seems to be about them being at the end of the string, where they may or may not be relevant. In this case, it seems not.

Answer (score 2):

If the null terminator is always at the end, you could use `std::strcmp`.

Otherwise you can write the loop yourself to iterate both strings and compare the characters, with special rules when encountering the terminator.

A less efficient version can be implemented purely using standard algorithms: Create a copy of each string with the terminators removed (`std::copy_if`), and then use comparison operator of `std::string`.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike C-style strings, `NUL` is a valid character for `std::string` and will be treated no difference as other characters.

Therefore, if one of your `std::string`s suffixes a `NUL` character and, that is not your want, you may should better figure it out why a `NUL` was included in the first place.

If you can't locate the source and fix it, there are two general workarounds.

**(1) Trimming the string before the comparison**

you can use a `trim()`-like funcion from third-party libraries, e.g. boost; or write your own implementation.

This function simply removes `NUL` character(s).

**(2) Comparing strings in C-Style**

use `std::string::c_str()` to obtain a c-style string and then use function like `strcmp` to do comparison。

Note, if there is a `NUL` character in the middle of the string, like `ab\0c`, this workaround would provide you a incorrect result.

Answer (score 0):

If you are comparing two strings, one of length 4 `"abc\0"` and one of length 3 `"abc"`, of course they are not going to compare equal. The fact that one of the characters is a `NUL` is not relevant here.

If you're trying to see if one string is the same as the other except that it has a `NUL` embedded in it at the end - that can be written thus:

```
std::string s1{"abc\0", 4};
std::string s2{"abc"  , 3};
return s2.length() == s1.length() - 1 && // sizes differ by one char
       s1.back() == '\0' &&              // last char is a NUL
       s1.compare(0, s1.length() - 1, s2) == 0; // all the other ones are the same
```